# Create React App - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: reactjs, ssl, npm, certificate, create-react-app

Based on https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app I run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

But I get this error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/js-tokens/-/js-tokens-4.0.0.tgz: unable to get local issuer certificate".
```

I tried it a week ago and it worked for another project. Now it doesn't seem to work anymore.
The folder structure is not created.

I have tried to set the strict-ssl to false but it doesn't fix the problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: try creating a folder called my-app, Open the terminal in **my-app** folder and then run `npx create-react-app .` or if the problem presists try it with **npm** : `npm install create-react-app -g` and then `create-react-app my-app`

Comment: In their docs they don't recommend this: "If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version."

Comment: @paulalexandru thank you, your suggestion to uninstall create-react-app global fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Turning the strict ssl flag to false worked for me

yarn:
`yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g`

npm:
`npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g`

Comment: Please describe the resolution in more detail with more insights like explaining the actual reason, add you working code snippet and steps to perform to eradicate the issues.
For more details visit StackOverflow's guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set strict ssl 'false', it is working for me

`yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, so I will answer because I don't found solution with others topics.

To solve this problem, try:

`npm install create-react-app -g` then
`npm audit fix`

so, after that try again

`npx create-react-app your-app-name`

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

`Error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com..." unable to get local issuer certificate` means that the local certificate cannot be found and that SSL key validation has been ignored.

According to the npm docs:

`strict-ssl`

Default: true
Type: Boolean
Whether or not to do SSL key validation when making requests to the registry via https.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/config#strict-ssl

---

According to the yarn docs:

`enableStrictSsl`

Define whether SSL errors should fail requests or not. If false, SSL certificate errors will be ignored.

https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#enableStrictSsl

---

Running:

`yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g`

`yarn config set enableStrictSsl false -g`

***OR***

`npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g`

globally sets `strict-ssl` to false, disabling SSL key validations when making requests to the registry via https making it insecure.

---

To fix your problem:

Run:

`yarn config set "strict-ssl" true -g`

`yarn config set enableStrictSsl true -g`

***OR***

`npm config set "strict-ssl" true -g`

to enable SSL key validations globally.

Then run:

`npx create-react-app your-app-name` to create a react app.